# Python Apply Low Pass Filter On Some Data

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, opencv, scipy

I have a .txt file which includes some frame difference of a video.
The project is to remove noise and stabilize a video using these frame differences and a low pass filter.

The Vibrated2.txt file is:

```
0.341486, -0.258215
0.121945, 1.27605
-0.0811261, 0.78985
-0.0269414, 1.59913
-0.103227, 0.518159
0.274445, 1.69945
, ...
```

How can i apply a low pass filter on this data?

I tried this but it didn't work!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter

video= cv2.VideoCapture('Vibrated2.avi')
freq = (video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
cutoff = 5

data = np.loadtxt('Vibrated2.txt', delimiter=',')

b, a = butter(5, (cutoff/freq), btype='low', analog=False)
data = lfilter(b, a, data)
```

Any help? Any idea?

Comment: What problem occured?

Comment: The goal is to stabilize video. It makes no change on the video. I don't even know whether i'm doing the right thing or not. I've asked another detailed question in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368246/python-video-stabilizer-using-low-pass-filter

Comment: When you already have the exact frame differences, why can't you just move every image by that amount and pad it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how your txt file is structured, but if you want to apply a low pass filter on your frame differencing output, i guess you want to make it binary?

```
def icv_check_threshold(pixel_value, desired_minimum_value):
    if pixel_value < desired_minimum_value: 
        return False 
    else:
        return True
```

And for the frame differencing:

```
def icv_pixel_frame_differencing(frame_1, frame_2):
#  first convert frames to numpy arrays to make it easier to work with
    first_frame = np.asarray(frame_1, dtype=np.float32)
    second_frame = np.asarray(frame_2, dtype=np.float32)

#  then compute frame dimensions
    frame_width = int(first_frame[0].size)
    frame_height = int(first_frame.size/frame_width)

#  we then create a stock image for differencing output
    frame_difference = np.zeros((frame_height, frame_width), np.uint8)

   for i in range(0, frame_width - 1):
        for j in range(0, frame_height - 1):
        # compute the absolute difference between the current frame and first frame
            frame_difference[j, i] = abs(first_frame[j, i] - second_frame[j, i])
        # check if the threshold = 25 is satisfied, if not set pixel value to 0, else to 255
        # comment out code below to obtain result without threshold / non-binary
            if icv_check_threshold(frame_difference[j, i]):
                frame_difference[j, i] = 255
            else:
                frame_difference[j, i] = 0

    cv2.imwrite("differenceC.jpg", frame_difference)
    cv2.imwrite("frame50.jpg", first_frame)
    cv2.imwrite("frame51.jpg", second_frame)
    return frame_difference
```

I hope that this helps. Also here is [a link](https://github.com/gromoglasov/frame-differencing-object-tracking) to a project with frame differencing I was working on.